# Undetermined coefficients (Trig functions) order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the equation 
$$y''-3y'+2y=5\cos(2t),$$
 the "guess" for the homogeneous trig function on the right using undetermined coefficients would be (as I am taught):
$$ A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t)=5cos(2t).$$

Then I proceeded to solve for the $ A$ and $B$.

My question is:

If it's $\cos(t)$, does the "guess" have to be in this exact form $(A\cos(x)+B\sin(x))$ ?  Meaning does the cosine have to get the "$A$" constant?

I tried this same equation using $A\sin(2t)+B\cos(2t)$ and did not get the same answer.  The correct coefficients are; "$A$" is $(\frac{-1}{4})$ and "$B$" is $(\frac{3}{4})$.
What I got when I switched was $A=(\frac{-5}{4})$ and $B=(\frac{15}{4})$.

Can you simply not switch the order?
Thanks.

Comment: I know, I'm asking if the order was switched ({ Asin(2t)+Bcos(2t) }) for the same original 5cos(2t) would we get the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter if you solve for $y= A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t)$ or $y= B\cos(2t)+A\sin(2t)$ your final solution should be the same.

$$ y= A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t) \implies y'= -2A\sin(2t)+2B\cos(2t)$$

$$ \implies y''=-4A\cos(2t)-4B\sin(2t)$$

plugging in the equation, $$ y''-3y'+2y=5\cos (2t)$$

We have to solve for $A$ and $B$.

I came up with $A=-1/4$ and $B=-3/4$

Thus my solution for the particular part is $$y=-1/4\cos(2t)-3/4 \sin(2t)$$

Comment: @MisterOH Thank you for your attention.